# Haskell: restrict "a" to certain types?

Tags: haskell, types, tuples

I have a tree intended to contain a tuple at each node:

```
-- Should be initialized with `a' as a tuple of (Int, Int) or (Float, Float)
data MMTree a = Empty | Node a (MMTree a) (MMTree a) deriving Show
```

Is there any way to restrict `a` so that `MMTree` can *only* be initialized with specific types; namely, `(Int, Int)` or `(Float, Float)` rather than any old type?

Comment: Create a private type class and instantiate it only for those types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. You can use generalized algebraic datatypes (GADTs, http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT), which exactly do what you need (type of result can depend on used constructor). As a simple solution, you can make a constructor for each possible node type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data MMTree a where
  Empty :: MMTree a
  NodeI :: (Int, Int) -> MMTree (Int, Int) -> MMTree (Int, Int) -> MMTree (Int, Int)
  NodeF :: (Float, Float) -> MMTree (Float, Float) -> MMTree (Float, Float) -> MMTree (Float, Float)
```

However, this solution isn't very good (because you'll need to add more constructors if later you'll want to use the same tree type for other elements). So, `DataKinds` and `TypeFamilies` to the rescue:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data TreeType
  = TInt
  | TFloat

type family Elem (t :: TreeType) where
  Elem TInt = (Int, Int)
  Elem TFloat = (Float, Float)

data MMTree (t :: TreeType) where
  Empty :: MMTree a
  Node :: Elem a -> MMTree a -> MMTree a -> MMTree a

test1 :: MMTree TInt
test1 = Node (1, 1) Empty Empty

test2 :: MMTree TFloat
test2 = Node (2.0, 3.0) Empty Empty
```

This is the solution if you really would like to restrict used types in `data` declaration. However, I would like to suggest an easier solution: just leave your tree definition as is, and if you would like to process a tree where nodes are expected to contain tuples of numeric values, just write functions with type signature like that:

```
someFun :: (Num a) => MMTree (a, a) -> r
```

Answer (score 4):

If you instead write

```
data MMTree a = Empty | Node (a, a) (MMTree a) (MMTree a) deriving Show
```

you can guarantee that the nodes will have tuples of the same type in them. This isn't exactly what you asked for, but may be all you actually need. Certainly it simplifies the problem: now you only have to restrict `a` to Int or Float, rather than a tuple of them, if that's really what you need.

Comment: In addition to this you can make the data constructors private and then make smart constructors that are exported by the module.  These constructors would only allow, for example, `Num a => (a, a)` values to be stored in it i.e. `empty :: Num a => MMTree a` and `node :: Num a => (a, a) -> MMTree a -> MMTree a -> MMTree a`, much like `Data.Map.empty` and `Data.Map.fromList`.